# Dynamic pages: include specific aside for specific content

Tags: php

I have the following code to include pages dynamically:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="aside">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <?php
        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? sanitize($_GET['page']) : 'home';
        if (!include 'pages/'.$page.'.php') require 'pages/404.php';
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `#aside` has static content.
I want to include a specific content for the `#aside` depending on the page selected. For example, if the user goes to 'Home' and 'About', I want the 'default' aside. But if the user goes to 'Documents' I want a 'Sections' aside.
I know I can just include each aside from every page, but that's not effective. I also don't want the user to be hable to set the aside as the main content, so they have to be in different folders or something.
I'd like to know an effective and not so complicated way to do this.
Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Never use a value from superglobals, before you validate it :)

Comment: Can you give examples, of what you want to do with the aside? Is this HTML5? If this question is not about the main, remove it!

Comment: What if I go to `www.example.com?page=../page_you_dont_want_me_to_visit`?

Comment: If you have a page parameter, you can output the #aside content based on an if-else block that checks the value of the $page variable.

Comment: markus: It's all in the question. It doesn't have to do with HTML. I want to include an specific sidebar depending on the page the user accessed. If the user went to 'Home', y want the 'Default' sidebar. If he/she goes to 'Documents' I want a sidebar called 'Section'.

Comment: Madara: I already knew that problem, thanks for pointing it out though. I will just check if the file exists in the pages directory. That will fix the problem.

Comment: @KingCrunch, it's validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and collaboration. Although none of the answers did exactly what I was looking for, they showed me other ways to approach this issue and guided me to decide what method to use.
I came up with what I think is the simpliest way to do this:

1. I set my folder structure as: **pages/aside** and **pages/main**
2. I set up an array($asides) with the **aside** files as the *keys* and the **main** content files as the *values*.
3. Then I check if the requested file exists in the **main** folder.
4. **If it doesn't exist**, I redirect the user to the 404 page. **If it does exist**, I loop through *$asides* to see which *aside* is asigned to that *main* content page.
5. If it doesn't belong to any of the establisged *asides*, then I include the **default** aside.

```
$asides = array(
        'aside1' => array('page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'),
        'aside2' => array('page5', 'page6')
    );

$page = (!empty($_GET['p'])) ? sanitize($_GET['p']) : 'page1';

if (file_exists("pages/main/{$page}.php")) {

    foreach ($asides as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($page, $asides[$key])) {
            $aside = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isset($aside)) $aside = 'default';

?>
    <div id="aside"><?php require "pages/aside/{$aside}.php"; ?></div>
    <div id="main"><?php require "pages/main/{$page}.php"; ?></div>
<?php

} else {
    header('Location: ?p=404');
}
```

The bounty goes to **Madara Uchiha** because in my opinion, his answer is simple an effective. Thanks again to all of you who helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep which sidebar goes on which page in a database, and then query that database for the correct sidebar to include.

A table structure may look like this:

- Table *sidebars*: ID | path | name | more info on sidebar...
- Table *pages*: ID | path | name | more info on page...
- Table *sidebars-to-pages*: page_ID | sidebar_ID

This approach even allows you to place multiple sidebars on a specific page.

Comment: Might very well be that a database is overkill for this.

Comment: @markus-tharkun: I'd argue it isn't. Especially if he's planning to scale.

Comment: Why can't argue, we don't know enough. But I don't think he's building a CMS.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I would prefer to keep it away from the database though. I'll wait for more answers to see other appoaches.

Comment: I don't see how this deserved a -1.

Answer (score 1):

What if you did this?

```
<?php
ob_start();
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? sanitize($_GET['page']) : 'home';
if (!include 'pages/'.$page.'.php') require 'pages/404.php';
$contents = ob_get_clean();
?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="aside">
        <?php include($aside); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $contents; ?>        
    </div>
</div>
```

and $page.php would look like:

```
<?php $aside = "sidebars/default.php"; ?>
<p>HTML for #main<br />
goes here</p>
```

Comment: You are looking for a CMS, and there is all KIDNS of solutions out there, but they get increasingly complex, this is a very extensive topic in which I have spent a great deal of time on.  But it's fun :) Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: The problem here is that I have 'aside's that go with multiple 'main's. For example: the default aside goes with home.php and also about.php. I could just include the aside in each page, but I want a more effective way to achieve this.

Comment: That's what I don't want to do. I don't want to include the sidebar in each $page.php, nor I want to have a huge switch statement. I want something more effective, if possible.

Comment: Lol, well what I just updated is about as simple as you can get. I am not sure how versed in PHP you are, but basically it stores everything outputted my $page.php in $contents and then the rest makes sense (look at output buffering)

Comment: Still having to include the aside in each page. Well, maybe that's the only way. I'll wait for more answers.

Comment: Really, that is the most simplistic answer.  The only other option would be to have an array with each sidebar, and match it against each page ($sidebars = array("default"=>array("/","/about","/about/us")); ) but then you have to add a new entry for every page you make

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. I also came up with some folder structure, following this rule: 'pages/{aside}/{page}'. So it would be: pages/default/home.php, pages/default/about.php. Then you scan the dir and check in which folder the $page is. But I think it's too much just for showing some pages.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that would be an unnecessary use of processor time, and as the site grew, it would only get even worse in performance. When writing a CMS, it is better to take time and do it correctly then to spend time worrying about making it "faster" to code, because it always ends up taking longer lol (trust me ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this that are all more-or-less equal.  I almost always use a config.php file for sites to hold whatever global information I want every page to have.  At the top of every page, you just call

```
<?php 

    require_once('config.php');

?>
```

In that config.php file, you could have an array listing your page names and the file you want included for each page, as well as a function that returns the content, like so:

```
// this lets you call includes relative to the site root
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

$defaultAsideContent = 'includes/default.php';

$asideContent = array(
    'index.php' => 'includes/include-1.php',
    'document.php' => 'includes/include-2.php'
);

function getAsideContent() {

    global $asideContent;
    global $defaultAsideContent;

    $content = $defaultAsideContent;

    // get the requested page
    $pageFull = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // strip URL variables
    $pageParts = explode('?', $pageFull);
    $page = $pageParts[0];

    // loop throught the array and see if there is specific aside content for the page
    foreach($asideContent as $key=>$value) {
        if ($page == $key) {
           $content = $asideContent[$key]);
        }
    }

    include($content);
}
```

Lastly, wherever you want your aside content to show up, just do

```
<?php getAsideContent(); ?>
```

When you create a new page, if you want specific aside content, just edit your config file.  Just FYI, didn't test this at all, probably has bugs, but you get the jist.